# Can I travel to European Countries with National Visa D?

Tags: international-travel, europe, eu

I am planning to pursue Masters program in Geneva and is it possible to travel and look for jobs in EU Countries.

Comment: The flag to move this to expatriates is misguided - the post includes OP's intention to study abroad (in Switzerland) as context, but the actual question is about short-term travel to other countries during that time. This is the right place.

Comment: The question does not clarify if the OP allready has a Student D-Visa to enter the Schengen Area. Any reasonable answer would need that answer and when yes - then it an Expatriates question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson No, it's not. The question is whether possessing a Swiss D visa allows short-term travel to other EU countries. Whether OP already has the visa or merely plans to acquire it at some point in future is irrelevant, as they're not asking anything about the process of acquiring it or about living in Switzerland. They're asking about their options for short-term travel to other countries while in possession of a Swiss D visa. That is a travel question, not an expats question.

Comment: @ChrisH The question is whether an **expatriate** (holder of a D-Visa for **long** term stays) is different from that of a 3rd country national that needs a C-Visa (**short** term stays) is different. The answer to that is: yes it is different and therefore does not belong here but in the area that concentrates on expatriate conditions.

Comment: @MarkJohnson being an expatriate does not mean every question OP has belongs on expatriates. In this case it is relevant and important background information to get the correct answer, but the question is not about living abroad; it is about requirements for short-term travel (while happening to live abroad). Any answer will be a summary of OP's rights/obligations when seeking to enter, on a short-term basis, countries other than the one in which they are living. It is absolutely on-topic here.

Comment: @ChrisH But in this case it is. As D-Visa holder the 90 day rules applies for vists, but not for the searching for jobs (in most Schengen Countries). For that some form of a Job Seeker (National D-Visa) is needed. Both expatriates topics.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but OP doesn't want to move to those other countries; they want to enter them on a short-term basis to look for jobs. The long-term Swiss visa is irrelevant, except to the extent it affects OP's rights to short-term visits to countries other than Switzerland. If the Swiss D visa doesn't allow intra-Schengen for OP's purposes, that is **the answer to the question**, not a sign that the question is off-topic.

Comment: @MarkJohnson information on how OP *can* achieve their aim is certainly helpful in addition to answering the specific question, and if the only way to do that is by acquiring a long-term visa then any further questions OP has about how to acquire such a visa would indeed be questions for expatriates. But OP hasn't asked those questions, OP has asked whether or not their Swiss D visa would allow for short-term travel to countries other than Switzerland. That is a question about short-term travel, not a question about long-term stays abroad.

Comment: @ChrisH I read this differently: *is it possible to travel **and look for jobs** in EU Countries*

Comment: @MarkJohnson there's nothing wrong in general with looking for jobs as a short-term visitor.  Different countries have different requirements in that regard, and the requirements are not uniform in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

With a valid Swiss D visa, you can travel in *other* Schengen countries *as if* you had a 90/180, multiple-entry Schengen visa.

- You **cannot** travel to EU countries which are outside the Schengen area (e.g. Ireland, or currently the UK).
- Days spent in Switzerland do not count for the 90/180 rule. Days spent in Schengen countries other than Switzerland count. The 90/180 rule applies over any combination of visa.
- In those Schengen countries, you can do what any business traveller can do -- you can **talk about** working, but you are not allowed to **start** working (not even unpaid internships, and not even for a single day).

Comment: Relevant EU rules (e.g. for Directive 2004/38/EC article 10 and 20 card holders) should still apply to the UK until the end of the transition period in December 2020. Nothing will change in that respect in the next days. Rules regarding unpaid internship actually depend on the country. In fact, for a short (< 90 days), the appropriate procedure might actually be to secure a separate authorisation but not necessarily another visa.

Comment: @Relaxed, for January, the UK is an EU member which requires a separate visa. From February, it is a third country which requires a separate visa. The OP is in Switzerland on a D visa, not an Article 10 card or whatever.

Comment: If I thought the OP could travel to the UK I would have mentioned it, that's not the point. From February 2020, the UK will not merely be a third-country, it will be a third-country applying EU rules. Nothing relevant will change in “the next days” (which is not idiomatic by the way), the relevant limit is now December 2020. It's confusing to mention the UK leaving the EU in this context while failing to mention when the only relevant consequences will happen.

Comment: @Relaxed, I changed it to say that the UK is currently in the EU.